# Connect with remote MySQL Database from Herokou

Tags: heroku, google-cloud-sql

I am installing WordPress on Herokou app, I want to use external MySQL database that is hosted on Google SQL Cloud. I need a static IP or IP pool to enable on Goolges side firewall I can't figure out how to do so? or if this is a valid option using Herokou

Love to hear your thoughts

Answer (score 0):

Using the Google Developer Console, select your Cloud SQL instance, go to 'ACCESS CONTROL' tab and add your application static IP Address/IP pool to the 'Authorize Networks' section. This will enable access to Cloud SQL instance from those IP addresses.